# Share parent state between child components' states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

Learning React, I'm building a simple Calculator. Components model is:

```
- Calculator
  - Sliders (input[ref=cars])
  - Dashboard (p {this.state.cars})
```

`Sliders` is component with set of inputs, that should be transfered to `Dashboard` via parent `Calculator` state.

My goal is to make state value in `Dashboard` change on `Sliders`s input component change.

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cars: 0
    };
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="calculator">
        <Sliders
          cars={this.state.cars}
        />
        <Dashboard
          cars={this.state.cars}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function () {
    return {
      cars: this.props.cars
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Cars: {this.state.cars}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Sliders = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cars: this.props.cars
    };
  },
  handleInput: function () {
    var state = {
      cars: this.refs.cars.value
    }
    this.setState(state);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="sliders">
        <input type="text" ref="cars" onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.state.cars}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

As I've got, `handleInput()` is trigged, so state for `Sliders` is set. However, it's NOT "transfered" to parent `Calculator`'s state as 'cars'. So, `Calculator`'s state is not updated => `Dashboard` state is not udpated too.

**How to share Calculator's parent state between Sliders and Dashboard?**

I know, there are plenty of similar questions on SO, however it's hard to find the specific helpful case, especially when you're complete noob in React. So, sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components don't share state. The state of one component can become the props of another component though.

In your case, `cars` should be the state of `Calculator,` and `Slide` and `Dashboard` should only retrieve `cars` as props. If the input changes, `Sliders` should notify `Calculator` about the change so that it can update its state and rerender (which causes `Sliders` and `Calculator` to update as well):

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cars: 0
    };
  },

  onUpdate: function (cars) {
    this.setState({cars});
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="calculator">
        <Sliders
          cars={this.state.cars}
          onUpdate={this.onUpdate}
        />
        <Dashboard
          cars={this.state.cars}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Cars: {this.props.cars}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Sliders = React.createClass({
  handleInput: function (event) {
    this.props.onUpdate(event.target.value);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="sliders">
        <input type="text" ref="cars" onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.props.cars}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

As few components as possible should have state and state should be as high up in the tree as possible. See also [Props in getInitialState Is an Anti-Pattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)

Comment: thank you, Felix, helpful answer as always. event.value => event.target.value, I suppose?

Answer (score 1):

Pass parent as a prop to slider, and you wont need cars as a state in sliders.

This is one way of doing it, but FelixKing's answer is better.

```
var Calculator = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      cars: 0
    };
  },
  handleInput: function () {
    var state = {
      cars: this.refs.cars.value
    }
    this.setState(state);
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="calculator">
        <Sliders
          cars={this.state.cars} parent={this}
        />
        <Dashboard
          cars={this.state.cars}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
});

var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function () {
    return {
      cars: this.props.cars
    }
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Cars: {this.state.cars}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var Sliders = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {};
  },
  handleInput: function (value) {
    this.props.parent.handleInput(this.refs.cars.value);
  },

  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="sliders">
        <input type="text" ref="cars" onChange={this.handleInput} value={this.props.cars}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Comment: This tightly couples the Slider to the Dashboard, not ideal. [Felix's example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33347350/227299) shows how to keep them decoupled

Comment: The use of "parent" ?

Comment: Yes, now you cannot use a slider unless a parent is set. In Felix example, you can still create a slider that doesn't depend on a parent being set.

Answer (score 1):

In React you want to have one or several "smart" components, that handle state and "dumb" components. The "smart" components transfer the state down to the "dumb" component. The also inject event handlers, like in your case a handler for changing the amount of cars.
Your calculator is your smart component. It should also have a function to handle the state change.

```
handleCarsChange: function( newAmount ) {
  this.setState({ cars: newAmount });
},
```

Also don't make your initial state from `props` ([more Information](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html)). Props are made to change, use them directly in your render function like so:

```
var Dashboard = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Cars: {this.props.cars}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Or with the React 14 component function syntax:

```
var Dashboard = function(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Cars: {props.cars}</p>
      </div>
    );
};
```

Last but not least give the `Sliders` component a handler function to deal with the state change:

```
<Sliders
  cars={this.state.cars}
  handleCarsChange={this.handleCarsChange}
/>
```

And change the `handleInput` function in the `Slider` component:

```
handleInput: function(value) {
  this.props.handleCarsChange(this.refs.cars.value);
},
```